# Maximum average SQL -#1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, group-by, information-retrieval

I'm trying to display
movie
with
the
highest
rating. With the following SQL.
A
movie
rating
is
calculated
as
the
average
of
all
reviewer
ratings.
For the movie table, there is a movieID which is connected to a REVIEW table which contains movieID, and a rating (numerical value)

```
SELECT MOVIE.`movieID` , REVIEW.`rating` 
FROM MOVIE, REVIEW
WHERE MOVIE.`movieID` = REVIEW.`movieID` 
AND REVIEW.`rating` = MAX(AVG(rating));
```

but I keep getting an

## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.movieID,
       t2.rating
FROM
  (SELECT R.movieID AS movieID,
          AVG(R.rating) AS rating
   FROM MOVIE AS M
   JOIN REVIEW AS R ON R.movieID = M.movieID
   GROUP BY R.movieID) AS t1
JOIN
  (SELECT movieID,
          max(rating) AS rating
   FROM
     (SELECT R.movieID AS movieID,
             AVG(R.rating) AS rating
      FROM MOVIE AS M
      JOIN REVIEW AS R ON R.movieID = M.movieID
      GROUP BY R.movieID) AS t) AS t2 ON t1.movieID = t2.movieID
AND t2.rating = t1.rating;
```

You can't USE AGGREGATE functions IN 
WHERE clause, 
      try above query. Let me know IF it helps.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM MOVIE AS M
JOIN REVIEW AS R ON R.movieID = M.movieID
GROUP BY R.movieID
LI' at line 3

Comment: The code is now going to back to 1111 - Invalid use of group function :(

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT R.movieID AS movieID, AVG(R.rating) AS rating
   FROM MOVIE AS M
   JOIN ' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MOVIE.movieID, REVIEW.rating
FROM MOVIE
INNER JOIN REVIEW
ON MOVIE.movieID = REVIEW.movieID
HAVING REVIEW.rating = MAX(AVG(REVIEW.rating));
```

Comment: #1111 - Invalid use of group function still present! :( so frustrating I've been working on this for the last hour